# Importing an external UV map from png? If not, how to replicate?

Tags: uv

Complete blender noob here!

I'm a texture artist. I like to paint on 3D. So here's my situation:

I have a provided 3d mesh "dummy".
I have a provided UV map .png, for painting textures. (for additional detail, the UV map is HALF of the mesh, the painted textures are symmetrical, but the mesh is both sides/whole.)
Is there any way to assign the provided UV .png to the provided mesh?

I have tried the unwrap/smart unwrap, but the resulting UV map is nothing like the provided UV map.

How can I make them the same so that I can export the mesh as .obj and be able to use it for painting on in external software? It DOES have to match the provided UV.